# Issue when trying to run query on Fusion Tables with Google Maps

Tags: google-fusion-tables

http://zoofinder.us/map2.html
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1EawtHPl3kbnsXqzPPxQWPZOJeHX3i0XUOffz884

Trying to create buttons to load certain categories.

Would eventually like it to load with all Categories and have the ability to turn them on and off via buttons on the left.

My queries do not seem to be working.  For testing, I was trying to load all Farms and then toggle on the Zoos (and eventually toggle back off Zoos).

```
     var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
       query: {
         select: 'Location',
         from: '3092255',
         where: 'Category contains Farm',


  function updateMapZoosOn() {
 layer.setOption("SELECT Location FROM 3092255 WHERE Category CONTAINS Zoo");
  }
```

Any help please?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

CONTAINS is a string operator and your search values must be quoted e.g.
where: "Category CONTAINS 'Farm'",
Plus your layer.setOptions() syntax is incorrect.  You need the same type of {query: ....} options as you used when creating your layer

The [GMap FT Query Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#FusionTablesQueries) explains this.

Comment: Thanks!  I have been playing with this.  I can get it working when using an older method, but not using a newer one,

Comment: Sorry meant to post the links.  This one works http://zoofinder.us/map3-2.html  and this one does not http://zoofinder.us/map3-1.html - Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Well I took a quick look at both your apps and didn't see any obvious problems in map3-1. ( I'm not sure why you are using a key for the GMap 3 API)  But from the UI I can also see that in 3-1 only the Zoo layer is ever displayed.  The toggle does not work, so I think the issue is why only the Zoo layer is displaying (which should be the small_red icon)

Comment: I thought I was using v3?  Anyway, I got it all working with some tweaking - http://zoofinder.us/map.html

Comment: O.K. Good.  But you did go with the layer.setQuery() which is deprecated.  Not mentioned in the GMap reference. But I've noticed for a while now you cannot mixed the various methods.  E.g. created a FT layer via just the tableid and then using setOption() vs. setQuery.